docker in systemd-nspawn - permissions problems
I have setup a nextcloud docker container running fine except it cannot write to external storages.
The main process php-fpm is run as abc. Inside the container, the user is abc where:
# id abc
uid=3008(abc) gid=5004(abc) groups=5004(abc),1000(users)

and the external storage is a docker mapped read-write volume with the following Unix permissions, no ACL:
# ls -lh /mnt/logs
total 24M
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 3000 abc  2 Feb 17 22:54 files_inotify
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 3000 abc  2 May 11 20:54 files_scan
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 3000 abc 42 Jun 14 01:36 nc-pg
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 3000 abc  4 Jun 11 17:06 watcher

Could some mighty expert tell me how to fix it besides changing the owner to abc?
Environment:

Container image: linuxserver/nextcloud:29.0.2-ls324
Docker version:
26.1.4, build 5650f9b
Docker runs Alpine Linux 3.19.1 64bit/Linux 6.6.29-production+truenas inside LXC
Host: TrueNAS SCALE Dragonfish-24.04.1.1


I have found the culprit. There are still default ACL settings applied to the directories. I fixed it by removing them.
